# How use xaml to access Canvas.Left property of a ContentControl stored in DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I trid the following way. It does not work

```
<TextBox Height="30" Margin="90,82,218,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left), Source=CurrentDesignerItem}"/>
```

**CurrentDesignerItem** is the contentcontrol object I stored in DataContext.
How to access its Canvas.Left?

Comment: Is CurrentDesignerItem a property of some object stored in DataContext or is CurrentDesignerItem itself a DataContext for your TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer

```
 Text="{Binding Path=CurrentDesignerItem.(Canvas.Left)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, when specifying a Source, you need to include "DataContext" in the path:
Path=DataContext.Canvas.Left

Otherwise, find the output window of VS and it will tell you why it failed to bind.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FakeBindingPath' property not found on 'object' ''Vm' (HashCode=45082239)'. BindingExpression:Path=FakeBindingPath; DataItem='Vm' (HashCode=45082239); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```